# onclick срабатывает один раз

Tags: javascript, jquery

почему onclick один раз срабатывает )в форме если что добавляется textarea потом как нажимается крестик чтобы закрыть форму .удаляется и textarea )я уже не знаю что делать ,как снова при клике попасть туда

```js
function postqueshion(e) {

  e.preventDefault();
  $('.btn-ask').on("click", function() {
    $('#modalq').css({
      'margin-top': '-100%'
    });
    $('#mh').append("<textarea class=" + 'not-validate' + " rows=" + 1 + " cols=" + 50 + "  maxlength=" + 500 + " placeholder=" + ' Что' + '&nbsp' + 'хотел' + '&nbsp' + 'бы' + '&nbsp' + 'узнать?Например:' + '&nbsp' + '' +
      '«Хочу' + '&nbsp' + 'ходить' + '&nbsp' + 'с' + '&nbsp' + 'вами' + '&nbsp' + 'на' + '&nbsp' + 'пробежки' + '&nbsp' + 'в' + '&nbsp' + 'Москве,' + '&nbsp' + 'как' + '&nbsp' + 'это' + '&nbsp' + 'можно' + '&nbsp' + 'сделать?» ' + '  ></textarea> ');

  });
  $('#closes').on("click", function() {
    $('#modalq').css({
      'margin-top': ''
    });
    $('#mh').remove();
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" data-main-title="Задай свой вопрос кураторам Спарты, <br>которые уже прошли этот путь <br>Напиши свой вопрос в форме ниже" data-btn="Задать вопрос" data-goal="form08" data-additional="Вопрос кураторам Спарты" data-lp-form-id="8" class="btn-ask open-callback"
  onclick="postqueshion(event);">Задай свой вопрос</a>
```

когда я нажимаю второй раз на кнопку задать свой вопрос - textarea отсутвует )на счет nbsp не чего не говорите  ;D если только это не причина

Comment: зачем навешивать обработчик `click` внутри функции, которая вызывается по клику? убери к едрене фене функцию, а из ссылки убери `onclick="postqueshion(event);`. Это так, для начала